# Susbtitution in sed with spaces

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following variable in bash:

```
var1="this is ok"
```

and in a file I want fo make in all lines the subst:

```
_day 23. 45. 56. ...
```

to

```
this is ok_day 23. 45. 56.
```

so I add var1 to the start of the line

I tried with this

```
sed -e "s/_/${var1}"_"/g" ${filename}
```

but i get errors

I do not know if this is because the spaces. I aslo chaged `/` to `|` on sed but nothing

any hints?

Thanks

Comment: Knowing exactly which error sed gave you would help. Maybe $filename contains spaces? Always protect shell variables with double quotes (i.e. "$filename")

Comment: I think I can understand now why your methods do not work for me.

When I try with the "this is ok" example, all of them work.

But I try something different, now my string comes from:
  read st1 st2 st3 <<< $( cat ${filespecial} | grep c )
  stotal="$st1 $st2 $st3"

so it seems that the problem is with stotal: i do not know if ther reason is how I get it (read <<<) or the string concatentation, where i need spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can just use the shell

```
#!/bin/bash
var1="this is ok"
while read -r line
do
    case "$line" in
        _* ) line=${var1}$line;;
    esac
    echo $line
done <"file"
```

output

```
$ cat file
sldfj
_day 23. 45. 56.
alskjf

$ ./shell.sh
sldfj
this is ok_day 23. 45. 56.
alskjf
```

if you absolutely want to use sed,

```
sed -e "/^_/s/^/$var/" file
```

or with awk

```
awk -v var="$var" '/^_/{$0=var $0 }1'  file
```

Comment: I think I can understand now why your methods do not work for me. When I try with the "this is ok" example, all of them work. But I try something different, now my string comes from: read st1 st2 st3 <<< $( cat ${filespecial} | grep c ) stotal="$st1 $st2 $st3" so it seems that the problem is with stotal: i do not know if ther reason is how I get it (read <<<) or the string concatentation, where i need spaces

Comment: I think I can understand now why your methods do not work for me. When I try with the "this is ok" example, all of them work. But I try something different, now my string comes from: read st1 st2 st3 <<< $( cat ${filespecial} | grep c ) stotal="$st1 $st2 $st3" so it seems that the problem is with stotal: i do not know if ther reason is how I get it (read <<<) or the string concatentation, where i need spaces

Comment: its better to show in your original post what the sample filespecial looks like, what you are getting and show your desired output. If you are looking for lines in filespecial that have "c" (ie grep c) , then you are not getting the correct results into st1,st2 and st3 if there are many lines returned that matched.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use double quotes around `_` and you should not add a `g`lobal modifier:

```
sed -e "s/_/${var1}_/" "${filename}"
```

Whitespaces in `$var1` should not be a problem. Whitespaces in `$filename` can be a problem.

Comment: "_" is not added in substittuion

Comment: From your question, you want to replace `_` by `this is ok_`. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: I think I can understand now why your methods do not work for me. When I try with the "this is ok" example, all of them work. But I try something different, now my string comes from: read st1 st2 st3 <<< $( cat ${filespecial} | grep c ) stotal="$st1 $st2 $st3" so it seems that the problem is with stotal: i do not know if ther reason is how I get it (read <<<) or the string concatentation, where i need spaces

Answer (score 1):

The subst pattern you gave will not put `$var1` at the beginning of the line:

```
sed -e "s/^/$var1/g" "${filename}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var1="this is ok"; 
echo _day 23. 45. 56. | 
  sed "s/^/${var1}/"
```

outputs

```
this is ok_day 23. 45. 56.
```

Alternatively, use awk (no messing around with regexps, which aren't required)

```
echo _day 23. 45. 56. |
  awk '{print "'"$var1"' " $1}' < abc.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case enclose the "this is ok" with *single* quotes, not double quotes.

as in:

$ var1='this is ok'

Reason being the shell handles whitespace differently depending on the quotation marks used....